# PHP unlink file with no extension

Tags: php, unlink, pathinfo

I am trying to unlink files in a Directory which have no extensions.

I did following, but did not work:

```
      $fileInfo = pathinfo($this->outputPath);
      if($fileInfo['extension'] == NULL)
      {
          unlink($fileInfo['dirname'].$fileInfo['basename']);
      }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No error it just does not work

Comment: Your comparison with NULL is just wrong here. Enable proper PHP error reporting, and it will tell you that `$fileInfo['extension']` is not even set at all in such a case.

Comment: forgot `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` before `$fileInfo['basename']`

Answer (score 2):

As @CBroe noticed in comments:

> Your comparison with NULL is just wrong here.

Check for [empty](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)'ness instead:

```
  $fileInfo = pathinfo($this->outputPath);

  if(empty($fileInfo['extension']))
  {
      unlink($fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileInfo['basename']);
  }
```

Also, you missed a `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` between the `dirname` and the `basename`.

---

**Update:** As @hassan pointed out, `empty` is not the proper way to check for this either. That's because of directories `.` and `..` on unix-like systems will pass this test, which is not desired.

So, the proper way to check for files without `extension` would be:

```
  if(isset($fileInfo['extension']) === false)
  {
      unlink($fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileInfo['basename']);
  }
```

Comment: I think that `empty` is not the prober way to check for this

Comment: @hassan Yes, I've read your answer, and think you're right. But checking for `isset` means the same in case of `.` and `..` directories, doesn't it?

Comment: nope, pathinfo will return with empty extension for . and .. , so checking using empty will pass the `.` and `..`

Comment: @hassan Hmm. Seems like you're right. Updated my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

according to the [pathinfo manual](http://php.net/pathinfo) :

> Note:
>   If the path does not have an extension, no extension element
>   will be returned (see second example below).

so you need to check if the returned value has the extension element using [isset](http://php.net/isset) , **note that** using empty will pass the dot directories in unix systems, for example if you are iterating some directory empty will consider the `.` and `..` directories as an empty extension elements

```
// check if not isset
if(isset($fileInfo['extension']) === false) {
    // perform some action
}
```

or if in the future you want to perform some complex search [eg: recursive search for files that does not have extensions] you may use [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php)

```
foreach (new FilesystemIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    // check if some file extension is null
    if ($fileInfo->getExtension() == null) {
        // perform some action
    }
}
```